# How can I derive these $3$ fundamental $2\times 2$ matrices:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, rigid-transformation

1) The matrix that represents counterclockwise rotation about the origin by angle $\theta$

2) The matrix that represents flips across the line $x=y$

3) The matrix that represents flips across the $x$-axis

Of course, all these are basic and can be easily found by a Google search.

But, I want to work out how to *derive* it, so that there's a much better chance that I remember what they are, in case I need to use them.

So, I could start?

I want all $3$ matrices with respect to the standard ordered basis, $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$.

I guess the main difficulty is not knowing explicit formulas for the action on the basis -- if I had formulas, then the matrix computation algorithm is trivial.

So, I would like to figure out the formulas ... geometrically, I think.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: How to derive the formulas for rotation matrices (which involve $\sin$ and $\cos$) depends on exactly what your definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ are (for one definition, it is basically a tautology...).

Comment: Yes, @EricWofsey, so I am basically taking the parametrization $(cos(\theta), sin(\theta))$ for granted ... and claiming that the vectors of unit norm...land somewhere on the unit circle, since rotations are norm-preserving transformations.  Thanks for sticking with me on such a basic question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column is $F\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right]$.  The second column is $F\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\1\end{array}\right]$.
So just work out where $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ end up.

Comment: OP knows this, and is asking how to work out where they end up.

Comment: Right, @EricWofsey - from geometric intuition alone and without explicit formulas (I want to derive it from scratch), it is actually pretty tricky... hmm....

Comment: To this day, I still think that tricky pre-calculus / high-school plane geometry material is the hardest math to gain mastery of ... and this problem is a good reminder of why I feel that way...

Comment: If you rotate $(1,0)$ through an angle $\theta$, it goes to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$.  But $(0,1)$ goes into the second quadrant.  Think, for a small angle theta, then sin theta is also small, but cos theta stays near 1.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the basic but very helpful hint @Michael.  Yes, rotations are norm-preserving, so the vector (1,0) with argument 0 lands somewhere on the unit circle, after a rotation mapping ...

Comment: Hi @Michael, I have that T(1,0) = (cos(theta), sin(theta)) = cos(theta) * (1,0) + sin(theta) * (0,1), so I have the first column figured out.  but what is the image of T(0,1), with T being rotation by theta?  Shouldn't it also be (cos(theta), sin(theta)), since it should still land somewhere on the unit circle?  Or do I need to add some sort of translation, since the vector is (1,0) and so already has argument $\pi/2$?

Comment: so that perhaps T(0,1) = $cos(\theta + \pi/2), sin(\theta + \pi/2)$?

Comment: It will stay on the unit circle, just into the second quadrant.  The x-coordinate becomes slightly negative, but the y-coordinate remains near 1.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, @Michael - and then using sum of angles formulas, I now verified the second column of the rotation matrix.  Now onto the other two matrices....

Comment: I got the other two matrices - thanks again, @Michael, for initiating some helpful discussions :-) Have a great night,